# How can I use PHP with MDBootstrap (Pro) and Gulp 4?

Tags: php, gulp, browser-sync, mdbootstrap, gulp-browser-sync

Quite new to Gulp and would like to integrate PHP includes using MDBootstrap.
Here is part of my `gulpfile.js` if that helps any...

```
// Live Server
gulp.task('live-server', function(done) {
  console.log("Restarting server...");
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});
function initBrowser(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./dist/",
      directory: true
    },
    notify: false
  },function(){
    console.log("asdasd");
  });
}
// Watch on everything
gulp.task('mdb-go', function(done) {
  initBrowser();
  gulp.watch("**/*", {cwd: './dist/'}, gulp.parallel('live-server'));
  gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", gulp.parallel('css-compile'));
  gulp.watch(["dist/css/*.css", "!dist/css/*.min.css"], gulp.parallel('css-minify'));
  gulp.watch("js/**/*.js", gulp.parallel('js-build'));
  gulp.watch(["dist/js/*.js", "!dist/js/*.min.js"], gulp.parallel('js-minify'));
  gulp.watch("**/*", {cwd: './img/'}, gulp.parallel('img-compression'));
});
```

*EDIT*

Directory structure:

[image: Directory structure]

Top of gulpfile.js:

[image: img file]

It works flawlessly but I **need to use PHP**. I made a hacky gulpfile in the meantime using `gulp-php-connect` but it does not concatenate or combine the scss files correctly.

Perhaps someone knows how to integrate `gulp-php-connect` to make it work?

Comment: Hi David, please more explain from project directory structure

Comment: MDBootstrap has its package integrated with Gulp 4. What's the problem?

Comment: PHP. I want to use PHP. The gulpfile (as it is) does not work w PHP. When I click on a php page it downloads the file. Maybe it could be resolved on the other end, like an htaccess?